# Unable to connect to selected Mobile Data Service on Blackberry Simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I've installed MDS simulator it runs ans stays in console window, i've downloaded blackberry sim for 9530, all settings are default.

When i click browser and then click home page i got following error message: 
Unable to connect to the selected Mobile Data Service, please try again.

I'm connected to internet, however, i'm behind router, all firewalls are turned off, i'm on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you start up the MDS Simulator before the device simulator, and make sure you don't have anything else on your machine listening on port 8080 - many services and websites (TiVo server, Tomcat, etc.) listen on that port by default so it can be a little competitive over who gets to listen on it!

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 2 days trying various of the tips online about MDS (and there are many) but none helped me.

For me, the solution was to **turn off network registration** upon simulator launch in eclipse.

(posted in case someone with my problem googles to this page)